# Integer variable for range "not found on sheet"

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I continue to have issues with my code (I am self-taught so I'm far from an expert in Python or XLwings).  My method is as follows:

1. I copy a 4 column set of data (again of varying lengths) to a 2d array.
2. The data is then compared against a newly found set of a data and the matches are removed from the copied array.
3. The contents of the columns that were assigned to the original 2d array are then cleared of their contents.
4. The same array (with the matches deleted), is replaced at the same starting cell as the previous array.

In short, I copy the columns, remove the matches, clear the original cells, and then paste the new contents at the same starting cell as the original columns.  (Since the length of the column is not fixed, I assign this cell row to a variable "sht2Row".)

However, about 10% of the time, I get the following error:

```
    104         sht2.range((5,3),(sht2Row,10)).clear_contents()
    105         time.sleep(0.5)
--> 106         sht2.range((5,12),(sht2Row,16)).clear_contents()

    107         time.sleep(0.5)
    108         sht2.range("C5").value=BoughtData

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py in range(self, cell1, cell2)

    862                 raise ValueError("Second range is not on this sheet")
    863             cell2 = cell2.impl
--> 864         return Range(impl=self.impl.range(cell1, cell2))

    865 
    866     @property

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py in range(self, arg1, arg2)

    635             xl2 = self.xl.Range(arg2)

    636 

--> 637         return Range(xl=self.xl.Range(xl1, xl2))

    638 
    639     @property

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64         while True:

     65             try:


---> 66                 v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)

     67                 if isinstance(v, (CDispatch, CoClassBaseClass, DispatchBaseClass)):

     68                     return COMRetryObjectWrapper(v)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py in Range(self, Cell1, Cell2)

  47370         # The method Range is actually a property, but must be used as a method to correctly pass the arguments

  47371         def Range(self, Cell1=defaultNamedNotOptArg, Cell2=defaultNamedOptArg):

> 47372         ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(197, LCID, 2, (9, 0), ((12, 1), (12, 17)),Cell1 , Cell2)

  47374                 if ret is not None:
```

> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None,
> 0, -2146827284), None)

Does anyone know why this would occur?  In the past, I have occasionally received this error because I was working on code that talks to these sells but most of the time lately, I won't even be at the computer but will still receive this error.  I don't understand this.  If it is some issue with sht2Row then why isn't it occurring the first time I use the variable?  Regardless, how is it possible to get a "Second range is not on this sheet" error when sht2Row is just an integer?  I am really at a loss as to why this would only occasionally occur and why it would say that the range is not on the sheet...

This is my first time using this site.  I normally try to figure my errors out on my own but this one has me stumped...

Comment: What you get is not the "Second range is not on this sheet" exception. Google results for the value "-2146827284" indicate your cell indexes may be out of range. Perhaps surround line 106 of your program with try/except and print the value of sht2row?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I looked into that and unless there is some kind of redirect I do not understand going on, that should not be the issue.  I used the "print" command function to print the value of sht2Row immediately before each iteration and gave reasonable numbers each time...  The only thing I can think of is that I have iterations turned on in Excel itself.  Maybe that is somehow causing a conflict?